# Can a collection be modified by another thread during ToList()

Tags: c#, .net

```
class Sample
{
    private List<int> _list;
    public List<int> List
    {
        get 
        { 
            return _list.Select(p => p + p).Where(q => q % 2 == 0).ToList(); 
        }
    }

    public void Add(int n)
    {
        _list.Add(n);
    }

    public void Remove(int n)
    {
        _list.Remove(n);
    }
}
```

I have a situation similar to above in a multithreaded environment where `Add`, `Remove` and `List` are accessed by multiple threads simultaneously.

In some cases `Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute` is thrown in the `List` getter, which makes sense as threads can Add/Remove while the Select/Where operations are executing.

Can the list be modified by another thread during a call to `ToList()`?  Meaning, would changing the getter to

```
return _list.ToList().Select(p => p + p).Where(q => q % 2 == 0);
```

be enough, or do I need to resort to locks around access to `_list`

Comment: No; you can't do that.

Comment: Would you consider using [concurrent collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent(v=vs.110).aspx) ?

Comment: It is expensive getter I think

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no multi-threading protection in `List<T>`, so yes, another thread *could* modify the list during a `ToList` call. The results could be:

- Everything's fine, and the resulting list has the new value
- Everything's fine, and the resulting list doesn't have the new value
- It sets your hard disk on fire (or other undefined behaviour)

Basically, it is *not* safe to use a `List<T>` from multiple threads without external synchronization, unless *all* the threads are just reading from it. You either need synchronization (e.g. using [`SynchronizedCollection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668265.aspx) instead of `List<T>`, or handling the synchronization yourself), or a concurrent collection such as [`ConcurrentBag<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Actually after letting a test run for a while, it threw `Destination array was not long enough. Check destIndex and length, and the array's lower bounds.` which is close enough to setting my hard disk on fire for me.  Thanks Jon